# If $f(x)$ is convex on $[a,b]$, show $h(x) = \frac{f(x) - f(a)}{x - a}$ is increasing

Tags: analysis, proof-writing

I am unsure how to go about starting the proof. I know if $f(x)$ is convex, then for any $x$ we have:

$$f(x) \geq f(a) + f'(a)(x-a)$$

Which rearranged gives us

$$f'(a) \leq \frac{f(x) - f(a)}{x - a} = h(x)$$

I proved a result that said $f'(x)$ is increasing given $f(x)$ is convex, would that be relevant here?

Comment: The condition on convexity should include $a$. For example, $f$ defined as $f(x)=1$ on $(0,1)$ and $f(0)=0$ is convex on $(0,1)$. But $g(x)=\frac{f(x)-f(0)}{x-0}=f(x)/x=1/x$ is decreasing on $(0,1)$. Therefore, as written this statement is false.

Comment: Yes you're right, fixed.

Comment: You wrote the statement of the problem in the title and in the body of the post you only have conclusions supposedly derived from the hypotheses. The main part that needed fixing is the title's $(a,b)$.

Comment: Look this [question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2175792/prove-gx-fracfx-fax-a-is-increasing)

Answer (score 2):

For $b>x>y>a$, we have
\begin{align*}
f(y)&=f\left(\dfrac{y-a}{x-a}\cdot x+\dfrac{x-y}{x-a}\cdot a\right)\\
&\leq\dfrac{y-a}{x-a}\cdot f(x)+\dfrac{x-y}{x-a}\cdot f(a),
\end{align*}
then
\begin{align*}
f(y)-f(a)\leq\dfrac{y-a}{x-a}\cdot f(x)+\dfrac{a-y}{x-a}\cdot f(a),
\end{align*}
and hence
\begin{align*}
\dfrac{f(y)-f(a)}{y-a}\leq\dfrac{f(x)-f(a)}{x-a}.
\end{align*}

Comment: Don't use derivative, $f$ need no be differentiable.

Answer (score 0):

$$
f(a)+\lambda(f(b)-f(a)) \ge f(a+\lambda(b-a))\rightarrow \frac{f(a+\lambda(b-a))-f(a)}{\lambda(b-a)} \le \frac{\lambda(f(b)-f(a))}{\lambda(b-a)}
$$

now making $\lambda \rightarrow 0$ we have

$$
f'(a) \le \frac{f(b)-f(a)}{b-a}
$$

but choosing now $b = x$ we have $f'(a) \le \frac{f(x)-f(a)}{x-a}$ as expected.

Here $a \le x \le b$

Comment: Where are we using the fact that $f$ is convex?

Comment: If $f(x)$ is convex on $[a,b]$ then $f(a)+\lambda(f(b)-f(a)) \ge f(a+\lambda(b-a))$ !!